# Cucumber Java. Optional regex parameter in step with any symbols can't match

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, autotest

When I try create step with paramter which has dashes like this:

```
@And("^In history \"(.*)\" smth (opt1|opt2t---wo)$")
public void check() {

}
```

it is displayed with `'<param>'` as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQNvR.png)

and even then it doesn't work and shows as UNKNOWN STEP

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3Qcx.png)

But if I create without dashes it works well as parameters:

```
@And("^In history \"(.*)\" smth (opt1|opt2two)$")
public void check() {

}
```

it is displayed OK, as two separate steps and as parameter:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhpnf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbUOr.png)

Backwards slash doesn't help :(

```
@And("^In history \"(.*)\" smth (opt1|opt2-two)$")
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it converts to:` ?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I mean "so looks in feature file, when i choose it"

Comment: Still not clear. Choose where? In IDE? Can you reformulate your question? Say in the form "1. I have this feature file, 2. I have this step definition, 3. When I start test I get this result but expect this result". In other word it is worth having minimal reproducible example that one could take to their local environment and reproduce.

Comment: @AlexeyR. I updated topic again))

Comment: Ahh.. Now I see. You're talking about Idea Cucumber plugin. So you expect it would auto-suggest you two steps. One with `opt1` and another with `opt2-two` ?

Comment: absolutly right

Comment: @AlexeyR. Any suggestions?)

Comment: I was thinking of that. The thing is that it is actually the matter of IDEA plugin, not cucumber itself. I tried to fix expressions but only managed to have `<param>` in place of `opt` stuff in code assist. So no idea how to overcome this  bro... Probably it is worth raising a ticket in IDEA support since there is no issues section in plugin github.